# USB C - USB A cable connection for power source

Tags: power-supply, cables, usb-c, usb-pd

I'm trying to power a small microcontroller board using the USB-C of a smartphone, to do so I took a USB C - USB A that has 4 lines (Vcc, GND and 2 data), but I'm not able to get 5V out of it.

Simply testing the power line gets less then 1V and drops to 0V if a load is applied, I also tried putting data lines in pull-down with no results.

I don't need high power, so I'm fine with a simple solution (I can't implement any software protocol on data lines) to get few Watts.

Edit: I also tried with a USB-C phone charger with similar results.

Comment: Important details are missing. Is the adapter with a Type-A plug or receptacle? And the other end of the adapter has Type-C plug to a smartphone? Also not needing high power and then needing few watts is mutually exclusive. If you have a Type-A device, it must not draw more than 0.5W without negotiating.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to connect the usb-c to the smartphone (and use it as power source), on the other side (eventually cutting the cable and soldering directly the power line) I'll connect the device (to act as sink)

Comment: Afaik not every Phone can actively drive it's USB-port. Some newer Phones do support USB-PD, though. What model is your Phone?

Comment: I's a Samsung phone, but I had similar problems using a Samsung phone charger (with usb-c output)

Comment: You have to ask for power with the [USB OTG protocol](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/usb-onthego-otg-uses-and-support.html).

Comment: @Paa You never told if the cable had a Type-C on one end a Type-A plug or Type-A receptacle on one end. One you can use, one you can't.

Comment: Get an OTG lead - has an A receptacle on the other end

Answer (score 2):

In order to get 5v out of USB-C — with no data negotiation — you have to pull the cc1 and cc2 leads low, through 5.1k resistors iirc. I just did a PCB like this, and it worked.

Comment: This is correct, but you don't have access to CC lines if you chop an Type-C to Type-A adapter half in the middle. The resistors are already embedded in the Type-C plug, assuming it was a correct type adapter with a Type-A receptacle, and if the adapter had a Type-A plug, it is a wrong type of adapter anyway with wrong resistors. So this does not really answer the asked question.